# Recommended way to Install Magento 2 on shared hosting, Composer or archives

Tags: magento2, installation, composer

The Install Guide recommends installing the software using archives (not Composer) for a shared hosting environment.

However, from [Magento documentation](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/prereq/integrator_install.html):

> Everyone who uses the Magento software must install Composer to update components and Magento. If you install Magento using an archive, you don't need Composer to install Magento, but **you do need Composer for updates**.

And from [this article](https://blog.nexcess.net/2015/12/31/magento-2-and-php-7-availability/):

> Attention: Because Composer relies on third-party code, we **do not** recommend Composer for use on production sites.

Then what is the "best" way to install Magento 2?

Comment: Interesting addition on Composer not being used on production. Yes it is 3rd part code but used well the modules in composer are a wealth of benefits.

Comment: Something I saw earlier that should probably be taken into account when considering using the zip - https://community.magento.com/t5/Version-Upgrades-for-2-x/Update-on-failed-2-0-x-upgrades-with-zip-archives/m-p/27096#M33

Answer (score 2):

I'm not speaking for Magento but it doesn't seem like a good idea in general to install updates on a production site. In addition, we recommend you use the [`pub` folder](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/howdoi/deploy/deploy-to-prod.html#deploy-prod) as your root in production so as to prevent running the Setup Wizard.

Answer (score 2):

For shared hosting where you can't do a source code clone or checkout and can't run composer. I would upload the archive from Magento direct or your own local dev machine if you have one. Then ensure that you have the server Web root pointed to the pub folder. This stops access to the setup wizard and other non protected directories.

Answer (score 1):

You should use Bitnami : https://google.bitnami.com

It has a launcher and your magento will be in the cloud. It is amazing and very cost-efficient.

Comment: Thank you, I've never tried bitnami but will try it soon. Have you used it for a production site?

Comment: I am currently building a site for E.C.I and they are a multi million dollar company that deal with various telecom technologies. There is no difference between using Magento 2.0 regular install on shared server or Bitnami. It is the same software just that using bitnami it's going to be a cloud hosting which is far more performant and flexible once you get the hang of it :)